# How do I refer to a model defined later in a reference property in Google App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

In Django, one can refer to a model defined later by using a string:

```
class A(models.Model):
  b = models.ForeignKey('B')

class B(models.Model):
  pass
```

How do I do so using Google App Engine `db.Model`s? I've tried

```
class A(db.Model):
  b = db.ReferenceProperty('B')

class B(db.Model):
  pass
```

to no avail. Should I forward declare class B before A?

Comment: If you are just starting out, don't use db, use ndb. The KeyProperty does support the use of the Kind as a string, so you can have circular dependancies.

Comment: You will find yourself jumping through hoops to prevent ReferenceProperty derefencing and fetching the object.

Comment: Oh man, I'm working with a code library that uses db. Do you think it's easy to convert to ndb?

Comment: Also, if I use `ndb.KeyProperty`, is there an equivalent to `collection_name`?

Comment: No.  You do that query yourself.  `A.query(A.KeyProperty == SomeBKey)`

Comment: You should have a read on efficient use of ReferenceProperties with prefetching - see http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine  - If you iterate over objects with referenceproperties and your referring to them, it is very expensive due to the large number of roundtrips.

Comment: this will give you an idea why referenceproperties can be a pain, and the collection sets are only a slight veneer of convenience.

Comment: Aye :( So, now I might just store the ID of B in a `db.IntegerField` of A, then run a query to fetch the instance of B when I need it. This is really hacky, but oh well. :(

Comment: Why not use the KeyProperty, it's far more appropriate than an IntegerProperty and it isn't hacky.

Comment: but KeyProperty lacks `collection_name` ...

Comment: As I said collection_name just inserts an automatic query of collection_name into the target class.  The query I show below is the same query the collection_set name creates for you in the target class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't put the "B" in a string.  It should be:

```
    class A(db.Model):
        b = db.ReferenceProperty(B)

    class B(db.Model):
        pass
```

Comment: Except this won't work.  B is not defined.  The use of a string to represent the Kind can be used in KeyProperties in ndb.

Answer (score 1):

Using ndb

```
class A(ndb.Model):
  b = ndb.KeyProperty('B')

class B(ndb.Model):
  pass
```

To find all instances of A, that refer to B

A.query(A.b == somekey_for_b)

This could be a method of B which is the equivalent of a db collection set but is not automagical and doesn't have the issue of collection set name clashes

Alternately if you must stick with `db` then either change the order of class definition, or just use `db.Model` as the kind for the reference property definition rather than the actual class.  It will still work, it just won't check the specific Kind at update time.

You can validate that the correct kind is supplied by supplying your own validate method